# How to restrict user to change Account setting in Outlook 2007?

Tags: outlook-2007

In our company we have a local mail server (MDaemon). Every user has a local mail server account which is bind with his company mail id. In Outlook 2007 of every user's machine the Account setting is configured with his company mail id, local mail server as POP and SMTP account and  credentials for his local mail server account.

Now in Outlook under Account setting if someone changes the *User Informations* (Your Name and  E-mail Address fields), then the outgoing mail from that Outlook contains that Name and Email address in From field.

Suppose my name is **Arion Ban** and my email address is **arion.ban@mycompany.com**. And my account setting looks like this -

**User Informations**
Your Name : Arion Ban
E-mail Address: arion.ban@mycompany.com

**Server Information**
Account Type: POP3
Incoming mail server: mail.mycomapny.com
Outgoing mail server (SMTP): mail.mycomapny.com

**Logon Informations**
User Name: arion.ban
Password: *password*

My colleague's name is **John Hanks** and his email id is **john.hanks@mycompany.com**. Now I put John's name and email Id in my Outlook's *User Informations* under Account Setting. I keep *Server Informations* and *Login Information* unchanged. Now my Account Settings looks like this -

**User Informations**
Your Name : John Hanks
E-mail Address: john.hanks@mycompany.com

**Server Information**
Account Type: POP3
Incoming mail server: mail.mycomapny.com
Outgoing mail server (SMTP): mail.mycomapny.com

**Logon Informations**
User Name: arion.ban
Password: *password*

Now I am sending mail to somebody, the mail will be delivered with *Form* field contains John's name and email id.

I think it is very much a Company security concern. I have to stop this slip-out issue. Is there any option to restrict the account setting, so that no one can change his Outlook's account setting? Or is there any changes I have to make in our Local Mail Server, may be SMTP authentication (not sure)?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into using Active Directory Outlook policies to control access.

http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/policies.htm